# Why Does CSS in style Tag trum main.css?

Tags: html, css, vs-web-site-project

I have a single page website that I am creating. It's to host my resume online. I'm running into an issue with the resume section. I took my current resume and converted it to html in word. This also includes the style tags with the CSS. When I put this code into my website, anything after the resume in the website has the CSS from the resume.

For example after the resume I have a download button, a contact form, and a footer. All of those take on the CSS of the resume instead of the website.

Is there a way I can keep the CSS to just the resume section? For example have the Body of the Resume have class Resume  and then fit all of the CSS under class Resume .Resume {
CSS
}
???

Or is there another way to go about this? Instead of using main.CSS can I create a secondary CSS page?

Comment: Choose your selector in your style code based on where do you need to apply those styles. for example `.resume ...... the rest of a selector {styles}`

Answer (score 2):

CSS are always global to the whole page.

You can give an `id` to your resume section, and prefix all the CSS rules with `#id` so that the styles will match only elements from your resume.